# Detect vertical resize jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a login page in which I use a little javascript and jquery to vertically align the login box.

I also have an event on resize() to put the box in the middle again.

But, with resize(), everytime the user resize the window, the function is fired and this is a kind of ugly :))

So, I would like to know if there is a way to fire the function only on vertical resize.

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It will fire every time, but you can track the width to check for only vertical resizing:

```
// track width, set to window width
var width = $(window).width(); 
// fire on window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    // do nothing if the width is the same
    if ($(window).width()==width) return; 
    // update new width value
    width = $(window).width();
    // ... your code
});
```

Comment: Okay I didn't think about it.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of comparing heights for each situation where you want to detect vertical resize, you can create reusable events for horizontal and vertical resizing like this:

```
// Horizontal and vertical window resize events.
(function () {
    var win = jQuery(window),
        prev_width = win.width(),
        prev_height = win.height();
    win.on('resize', function () {
        var width = win.width(),
            height = win.height();

        if (width !== prev_width) {
            win.trigger('hresize');
        }
        if (height !== prev_height) {
            win.trigger('vresize');
        }

        prev_width = width;
        prev_height = height;
    });
})();
```

That way you can just drop that code in place once, and then use the events like this:

```
$(window).on('hresize', function () {
    // handle horizontal resizing
});

$(window).on('vresize', function () {
    // handle vertical resizing
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Got better solution:

```
$('#element').resizable({
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#element').height(ui.originalSize.height);
    }
});
```

Comment: FWIW - `resizable()` is part of jQuery UI, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

*As a complement to [Doublesharp's useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096600/5901015):*

**In my case, `window.outerWidth` worked better, and was stable to vertical resizes.**

Indeed, I had some troubles with `$(window).width()` : it (strangely!) happened to be modified also when I only resized vertically.